# RewriteRule not working in httpd.conf

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite, httpd.conf

I'm trying to make the following occur:

When I go to `http://www.mysite.com/b-pogs/20` (or `http://www.mysite.com/b-pogs/20/`), it internally redirects to `http://www.mysite.com/b-pogs/index.php?comic=20`.

The way I'm trying to do this is as follows (and I'll include everything that I think is relevant).

All of this occurs in my httpd.conf.

By the way, going directly to index.php and using getters works perfectly right now.

```
Alias /b-pog /var/www/b-pog

<Directory /var/www/b-pog>
    RewriteEngine on
    RewriteRule ^/b-pog/([0-9]+)$ /b-pog/index.php?comic=$1 [PT]
</Directory>
```

When I go to `http://www.mysite.com/b-pog/20` (or `http://www.mysite.com/b-pog/20/`), it gives me a `The requested URL /b-pog/20/ was not found on this server.`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved my problem (I believe). If anyone wants to correct this solution, please do. It seems kind of wrong.

I just removed the `<Directory>` and `</Directory>` parts because it wouldn't really matter regardless. I'm not sure if there's anything they would do, anyways.

It seems to be working.

Comment: If you remove `/b-pog` from the regex and leave the <Directory> directive in your question, it should work. The reason is the URI-path tested in the rule's regex does not include the directory where the rule is, so can't be included in the regex either. Or, remove `/b-pog` from the <Directory> path.